# cURL - Bad Request (Invalid Number)

Tags: php, http, curl, http-status-code-400

I have set up a small PHP script on my system (running XAMPP) and it is working perfectly fine but when I upload it to my web server it says: **Bad Request (Invalid Number)**. What may be the reason?

Here is my code:

```
$url = "http://domain.com/filename.aspx?client=saad%40domain.com&oper=d&gname=g1";  

$options = array(  
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,  
  CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,  
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,  
  CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",  
  CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)",  
  CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,  
  CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,    
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,  
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,  
  CURLOPT_POST           => true,  
);  

$ch = curl_init($url);  
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);  
$content = curl_exec($ch);  
$header = curl_getinfo($ch);  
curl_close($ch);  

print_r($header);  
echo $content;
```

And the header array shows:

```
Array
(
    [url] => http://domain.com/filename.aspx?client=saad%40domain.com&oper=d&gname=g1
    [content_type] => text/html
    [http_code] => 400
    [header_size] => 129
    [request_size] => 337
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.034575
    [namelookup_time] => 0.029746
    [connect_time] => 0.030606
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.030615
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 37
    [speed_download] => 1070
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => 37
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.03455
    [redirect_time] => 0
)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you running XAMPP on the webserver too? All it says is Invalid Number? http://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/cc786188%28WS.10%29.aspx has a list of various reasons for this error.

Comment: No, the web server is running CentOS/Apache/cPanel. I have seen this URL but it gives no clue. I wonder which "invalid number" is it talking about.

Comment: I would try reducing your options significantly and building them back up, testing each time. If it still gives you an error with nearly no options, then something strange is going on.

Comment: You were right, reducing the options helped. It is actually the CURLOPT_POST option that was creating an issue.

Answer (score 6):

Removing the CURLOPT_POST option resolved the issue. It wasn't however creating any problem on my local PC.

Comment: The question is why... Here is a good answer to that: http://www.brandonchecketts.com/archives/array-versus-string-in-curlopt_postfields